# How to implement module installation and uninstallation using Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, module, installation, uninstallation

I have a webapplication built using Zend Framework that contains a lot of modules. These modules are all "optional" and are used to make extended functionality avalible. Some of these modules write their own logs etc. I was thinking about how to implement installation and uninstallation behvaiour for these modules.

At first my idea was to let every module have a `InstallationController`, `UninstallController` etc and have these handle the installation. But then I started thinking about an approach that would involve letting each module contain `install.ini`, `uninstall.ini` etc. Then the core has functionality to pare and act upon these. An example of an `uninstall.ini` for the module `foo` file could be

```
[save_logs]
folder.remove.data.foo
folder.remove.modules.foo
file.remove.configs.foo

[complete : save_logs]
file.remove.logs.foo
db.table.truncate.foo_table1
db.table.truncate.foo_table2
```

Then the user would be presented with the options of `Complete` or `Save Logs` while running the uninstallation of the `foo` module. One of the upsides I can see with this approach is a common core mechanic that handles all the operations and the fact that no code actually part of the `foo` module would be running during the uninstallation.

I have never done this type of installation/uninstallation/update support on a webapp before so any ideas and tips would be nice.

Comment: I like this question because it addresses an issue which I will also face very soon.

Comment: Btw. I can obviously spare some rep. So if this doesn't get enough good answers, I'd be happy to sponsor a bounty.

Comment: You might find the following proposal interesting: http://framework.zend.com/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=16023853

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I very quickly drew up some initial thoughts before the morning meeting here at work. What do you think? Should this approach be considered and investigated more?
It's some pseudo code discussion format here and it is in no way the complete set of functions and classes, but I think the primary ides is clear enough.

```
class Foo_Installer extends Zend_Module_Installer
{
    // The modules bar and exporter are needed by this module
    protected $_dependencies = array('modules' => array('bar', 'exporter'));
        // Maybe this should be expanded to include versions like below. Prehaps even be able to
        // specify a formula of a version like '>2.3 && !2.4 && !2.6' if 2.5 and 2.6 is not compatible
        // for some reason or another.
        protected $_dependencies = array('modules' => array('bar' => '1.0', 'exporter' => '2.3'));

    // Tell the installer what 'script' to use. Should be able to use sources such as xml, ini, yaml, db etc
    // The install script should contain sections for install/uninstall and update process
    protected $_installScript = 'fooInstall.xml';

    // Place to look for files for update
    protected $_repo = 'http://www.foobar.com/repo';
}


class Zend_Module_Installer
{
    protected function _checkDependencies() {
        // Check if modules in $this->_dependencies are already installed
    }

    public function install() {
        $this->_checkDependencies();

        // Parses the given source of the install script and returns installSteps
        $installSteps = $this->_getInstallSteps();

        foreach($installSteps as $installStep) {
            $installStep->perform();
        }
    }

    public function uninstall() {

    }

    public function update() {
        // Connect to repo and check for a newer version of the module.
        // I think that prehaps a standard should be that modules are distributed
        // as zip-archives so only one file needs to be downloaded. On a update server
        // a file named after a standard 'ie packages' could be present that could be
        // read to determine what packages and versions of these exist on the server
        // and if there is a new version avalible to download.
        //
        // If so we download, unzip, check dependencies, check if dependencies we don't
        // already have installet are avalible at the server, download these and itterate
        // until no more downloads are necessery. Then we start runnin the Update()
        // functions of the downloaded modules in the correct order.
    }

    protected function getInstallSteps() {
        // parses the installscript and instanciates Zend_Installer_Step objects
    }
}


// Base class for steps during installation
// This apporach makes it easy to extend the installer to be able to do specific things
// in specific enviroments. Prehaps configure a some external hardware or whatever.
class Zend_Installer_Step
{
    public function perform();
}


// Functions to handle the actual logic of creating and deleting stuff.
// Some could be standard and some could be application specific
class Zend_Installer_Step_Create_File extends Zend_Installer_Step
{
}

class Zend_Installer_Step_Delete_File extends Zend_Installer_Step
{
}

class Zend_Installer_Step_Create_Folder extends Zend_Installer_Step
{
}

class Zend_Installer_Step_Create_Db extends Zend_Installer_Step
{
}

class Zend_Installer_Step_Create_Db_Table extends Zend_Installer_Step
{
}

class Zend_Installer_Step_Create_Db_StoredProcedure extends Zend_Installer_Step
{
}
```

Comment: Votes but no feedback :)... Someone must have some input. Should I dig a deep hole an burry this approach or do you think it could work?

Answer (score 3):

I will face this challenge too, so we can probably help each other. I'm just gonna add some of my thoughts to what you've already started outlining.

I think having an install/uninstallController would be overkill resp. too much redundant code.

What about an installer core module which handles all the install and uninstall operations of the software. This module would then look for the install.ini and uninstall ini files and perform the necessary actions accordingly. The module would also do default operation, if the directives in the install.ini are missing. This way you could make sure that you only need to put non-default behaviour into the ini files.

Comment: Yea, my thoughts exactly. Feels cleaner to have the functionality in the `Core`. Also if one uses the config approach it would be possible for developers of modules to decide if they would like to create ini, xml etc style config files since Zend Framework could handle that abstraction. The Core install/uninstall/upgrade module would then 'only' need to implement the mechanics of creating database tables, writing data to tables or existing files such as main config file etc, creating folders and so on. The Core module would also be responsible for rolling back the installation in case of error

Comment: i am pretty interested in both of your ideas , and i would like to support , i'd like to suggest to provide all these idea as draft in create something might be named `installable modules` for zend framework , and we can borrow some spec form wordpress plugin architecture  , nameing conventions , file locations , installer , i18n ....etc , it would be great

Comment: sounds good! I'm glad to see you mention wordpress. I have never looked at the code of the wordpress plugin system but in general it strikes me as one of the most simple and clear plugin systems in the PHP open source world.

Comment: could this be drafted as a regular zend_component? so we would have zend_modules, zend_modules_installer so everyone can actually implement their own solution?

Comment: yeah that is it , we could create a simple prototype  and then improve it upon the needs , go for it and i can collaborate with you

Comment: I don't know when I'll be needing this, probably second half of 2011. I'll definitely keep you posted and I'll follow this question here.

Comment: I will actually be needing this in the near future. I will see if it's generic enigh to warrant a zf proposal. One question that arises is, how would this be any different than the nerd for an installer for the main application itself. But prehaps the answer is a component that enables this functionality both on a application wide abd per module basis. Interested colaborators are wellcome to collaborate on a draft.

Comment: I'm not sure how you can abstract the installation process into a config file. I think a better approach would be a class for each module (implementing a standard interface) with an install() and uninstall() method. The core component can then provide easy ways for these methods to create/remove database tables and the like, as well as checking for updates. Also IMHO Wordpress is not a good model to follow for anything code-wise.

Comment: I think there are several good ideas floating around.  First, I do think there should be an ModuleAdmin module that is responsible for the (un)install processes.  That coupled with Tim Fountain's idea of each module that is able to be (un)installed having a single class implementing a standard interface (install() and uninstall())